# problem operating on time columns with value greater than 9999:59

Tags: excel

I need to operate on values greater than `9999:59` (up until `20000:00`) in Excel. I used `[h]:mm` format but it seems it is not possible to do operation (like summation of two column) for values greater than `9999:59`. 
I already have the data so it's not possible for me to write it in another format.
I tried other formats such as `[hhhhhh]:mm` and `[HH]:MM` which my colleagues told me but they didn't work too.
Is there any way to do this?

[image: IMG1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly **operate** on time values > `9999:59:59`

But you cannot directly enter values greater than `9999:59:59` into a worksheet cell:

From **Excel Specifications and Limits:**

```
Largest amount of time that can be entered:  9999:59:59
```

*The reason for your `@VALUE!` error in `I3` is because, when you entered `1000:12` into `H3`, since it is greater than the amount that can be directly entered, Excel has changed it to a text string.*

But see this:

[image]

The formula:

```
H3:  =H2+TIME(0,13,0)
```

If you must work with directly entered times greater than `9999:59:59`, then you can enter that time differently in some other column, and use a formula to convert it:

For example, enter the time as a decimal number, where the decimal represents the minutes (be sure to use leading zero's for minutes < 10.  eg 1 minute = 0.01)

```
F4: 10000.12    10000 hours  12 minutes
H4:  =DOLLARDE(F4,60)/24
```

[image]